# How current flows in an ideal wire?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

what are the assumptions that we make, that should be kept in mind when a current is flowing through an ideal wire of 0 resistance? And what is the speed of the electrons in an ideal wire? if I have a resistor connected to a ideal battery via a ideal wire, is the speed of electrons in the ideal wire the same as the speed of the electrons as they pass through the resistor?

Comment: This link may help: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html